# Object is not a function in Expo(react-native) app

Tags: react-native, expo

[image]

My App is not starting. Please help me. Is that the problem with the libraryies ot with the code?

**edit 1:**
another mistake when doing render

Error: Problem validating fields in app.json. See https://docs.expo.io/workflow/configuration/
• should NOT have additional property 'nodeModulesPath'.

***app.json file:***

```js
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.4",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "expo": "~41.0.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "firebase": "^8.2.3",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-41.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-stack": "^1.0.0-alpha11",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

**edit 2:**

I uninstalled react-native-stack, but there is a mistake: Error: Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-stack'

I installed it again:

```
npm install react-native-stack
```

Then I have the same problem in the render (look the first picture) and this mistakes in console:

1 (yellow)

```
`Some of your project's dependencies are not compatible with currently installed expo package version:
 - react-native-reanimated - expected version range: ~2.1.0 - actual version installed: ^1.13.2
Your project may not work correctly until you install the correct versions of the packages.
To install the correct versions of these packages, please run: expo install [package-name ...]`
```

2 (red)

```
`Error: Problem validating fields in app.json. See https://docs.expo.io/workflow/configuration/
 • should NOT have additional property 'nodeModulesPath'.`
```

The render answer:

```
 `√ Expo Webpack
  Compiled successfully in 5.25s

i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://0.0.0.0:19006/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from C:\Users\Лёха\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\webpack-config\web-default
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
```

**edit 3**

I was wrong, so I deleted react-native-stack again

```
npm uninstall react-native-stack
```

Then I deleted the import in App.js file:

```
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-native-stack'
```

I still have it in yarn.lock file, but I think `rm -rf node_modules` should work. I just don't understand, how to use it.

[image]
`

Comment: Remove the `useScreens();` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### EDIT

you are probably not having react-native-screens in your node_modules? For react-navigation for each module you are using you have other modules that you need to import in addition. This is not done automatically.

#### old answer

You are using `useScreens()` outside of a component. By the way `useScreens()` is deprecated and should be replaced with `enableScreens`

Comment: This is not even my code, it was in a module already, I have never edited it.

Comment: "react-native-screens": "^3.0.0",

Comment: It's installed.

Comment: then your version probably does not fit the version of react-native-stack. If useScreens() has been deprecated, it is probably removed in 3.0.0 and you need to go down with the react-native-screens-version or go up with react-native-stack

Comment: but react-native-stack version is "react-native-stack": "^1.0.0-alpha11"

Comment: it's the last version https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-stack

Comment: I do not know why you are using this old library in an alpha version, but if you have to, you would probably go down with the version of react-native-screens, but maybe you just want to use react-navigation and want to use @react-navigation/stack instead? maybe you should post your package.json dependencies

Comment: Well, I need to make navigation in my app, I do not need exactly these libraries, I just followed the tutorial and this is not working.

Comment: IF I understood you right I need to uninstall:
"react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4"
"react-native-stack": "^1.0.0-alpha11",

and install:
@react-navigation/stack 5.14.5?

Comment: replace the  with `"react-native-stack": "^1.0.0-alpha11",` with `"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.4"` - I do not know where this is coming from but it is wrong

Comment: I think react-native-stack shouldn't be deleted

Comment: Error: Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-stack'

Comment: `rm -rf node_modules` and `npm install` will clear some problems with old still installed dependencies and then you need to check where you are importing `react-native-stack` of course this dependency needs to be updated as well

Comment: Didn't get what rm -rf node_modules do. Is it like deleting the node_modules folder?

Comment: yes, `rm -rf node_modules` deletes the folder, sometimes old depencies are still there and with that you remove them.

Comment: okay and what should I do next? npm-install all the modules from app.json again? 
And the expo (because it is also in dependencies)?

Comment: use `npm install rimraf -g`
`rimraf node_modules`